# Pass interface as parameter in Kotlin

Tags: android, lambda, interface, kotlin

I want to pass an interface as parameter like this:

```
class Test {
    fun main() {
        test({})
        // how can I pass here?
    }

    fun test(handler: Handler) {
        // do something
    }

    interface Handler {
        fun onCompleted()
    }
}
```

In Java, I can use anonymous function like `test(new Handler() { .......... })`, but I can't do this in Kotlin. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In Kotlin you can do :

```
test(object: Handler {
    override fun onComplete() {

    }
})
```

Or make a property the same way:

```
val handler = object: Handler {
    override fun onComplete() {

    }
}
```

And, somewhere in code: 
    test(handler)

Comment: You can decalre function as:  `fun test(handler: () -> Unit)` (or other than Unit, if you want to return something)

Comment: How I can I use the lambda to implement callback feature (Java). I want the implementation in different class and invocation on that in different

Answer (score 5):

since your interface has only one function. you can convert it to SAM like this

```
fun interface Handler {
        fun onCompleted()
}
```

then you can just implement this interface using lambda instead and so reduce the overall written code. this is only possible in v1.4

Comment: thank you this is EXACTLY what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Attached is an example of how to pass an object by parameter that represents the value of the data type and invoke behaviors using interface inheritance.

```
fun main() {

    val customClass = CustomClass(
            object : First {
                override fun first() {
                    super.first()
                    println("first new impl")
                }
                override fun second() {
                    super.second()
                    println("second new impl")
                }
            }
    )

    customClass.first.first()
    customClass.first.second()

}

data class CustomClass(val first: First)

interface First: Second {
    fun first() {
        println("first default impl")
    }
}


interface Second {
    fun second() {
        println("second default impl")
    }
}
```

It is worth mentioning that with `super.first()` or `super.second()` the default behavior of the interface is being invoked.

It doesn't make much sense to pass a lamda with an anonymous object as a parameter, `lambda: () -> Unit` , if what we need is to invoke the functions.

GL

[Playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: @SarpBaşaraner What I had answered was like casting to an interface so it did not make much sense regarding the question. I already updated my answer. Thanks