# Pass different functions with different method signatures to a function as a parameter in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-permissions, higher-order-functions

I am working on an android application using kotlin as my primary language. I needed to ask some runtime permissions for some parts of the app. So instead of writing similar boilerplate code to ask for the permissions I decided to to write a separate static function that checks for the permission, and run a method. Here is the static function

```kotlin
fun permissionExecution(childFragment: Fragment, permission: String, expression: ????) {

    Dexter.withActivity(childFragment.requireActivity())
        .withPermission(permission)
        .withListener(object : PermissionListener {
            override fun onPermissionGranted(response: PermissionGrantedResponse?) {
                expression()
            }

            override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                permission: PermissionRequest?,
                token: PermissionToken
            ) {
                token.continuePermissionRequest()
            }

            override fun onPermissionDenied(response: PermissionDeniedResponse) {
                if(response.isPermanentlyDenied) {
                    openSettings(childFragment)
                }
            }

        }).check()
}
```

This code works perfectly when I passed in methods with no arguments. But I have some situations where I will like to pass in methods with different arguments types.

1. calling the method like this `permissionExecution(childfragment, permission, foo(string))`
2. calling the same method like this `permissionExecution(childfrgment, permission, bas(string, Int))`

what class type can I use for the `espression` argument in the `permissionExecution()` method

Comment: So, you want to execute some lambda from different screens when `onPermissionGranted`, right? Is the `onPermissionGranted` only gonna have `expression()` in it?

Comment: I'd say overload the function, because if you dynamically take function you still will require to know things inside by checks before calling it.

Comment: @sonnet, yes. let me explain it this way, the process of writing to external storage, reading phone contact, use phone camera etc. all require different android access permission, which required similar method of asking for permission. Firstly, you check for permission, if granted you run a piece of code (i.e the expression method). Most times each expression methods are different due to method signature. I am looking for  a catch all method signature for the expression.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu, writing an overload will require me to write separate ones for each method signature which is what I am trying to avoid in the first place. The function am calling has no impact in the `permissionExecution` function other than being needed to be called.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd need to change the signature of `expression`. `() -> Unit` is fine because your func `permissionExecution` is common. Just pass the lambda you want from other classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to include the function parameters in the definition of the lambda arument. You already have everything you need to call these other functions:

```
permissionExecution(myFragment, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) {
    foo(myString)
}

permissionExecution(myFragment, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) {
    bar(myString, myInt)
}
```

If you need the `PermissionGrantedResponse` to determine what these parameters are, you can define that as the function input:

```
fun permissionExecution(childFragment: Fragment, permission: String, expression: (PermissionGrantedResponse) -> Unit) {

    Dexter.withActivity(childFragment.requireActivity())
        .withPermission(permission)
        .withListener(object : PermissionListener {
            override fun onPermissionGranted(response: PermissionGrantedResponse) {
                expression(response)
            }
    //...
}

//...

permissionExecution(myFragment, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) { response ->
    foo(response.permissionName)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have implemented a common static func that checks permission and pass some lambda to it that will be invoked when permission is granted. I do not understand why you these lambdas need some argument parameters. Is the below implementation what you desire?

```kotlin
class CameraFragment {

  fun onCreateView() {
    permissionExecution(childFragment = arg1, permission = "perm", expression = {
      // open camera
    })
  }
}

class LocationActivity {
  fun onCreate() {
    permissionExecution(childFragment = arg1, permission = "perm", expression = {
      fetchLocation()
    })
  }

  fun fetchLocation() {
    // get location, do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the interest. But let me re-iterate the gist of the question, the `permisssionExecution` method is a static method. I am interested in a expression type that will work any function with any input argument types so far as its return type is unit.

Comment: There's no such thing. The common ancestor of functions with different numbers of arguments is `Any`. And how would the `permissionExecution` function know what to pass in for these arguments?

Comment: Thanks for the interest. But let me re-iterate the gist of the question, the `permisssionExecution` method is a static method. I am interested in a expression type that will work any function with any input argument types so far as its return type is unit. expression can be `startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT)` or  `writeFileToLocation(file, locationPath)` etc.

Comment: @ilatyphi95 If you write a few actual usecases in the question even with psuedocode, then that will help people better understand what it is you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

here is a not so elegant solution. I create a wrapper class with a single method interface like this

```
class Permissions(val childFragment: Fragment, private val permission: String, val runExpression: RunExpression) {
interface RunExpression{
    fun expression()
}

fun permissionExecution() {

    Dexter.withActivity(childFragment.requireActivity())
        .withPermission(permission)
        .withListener(object : PermissionListener {
            override fun onPermissionGranted(response: PermissionGrantedResponse?) {
                runExpression.expression()
            }

            override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                permission: PermissionRequest?,
                token: PermissionToken
            ) {
                token.continuePermissionRequest()
            }

            override fun onPermissionDenied(response: PermissionDeniedResponse) {
                if(response.isPermanentlyDenied) {
                    openSettings(childFragment)
                }
            }

        }).check()
}
```

}

then call the class like this each time I need the permission

1.

```kotlin
Permissions(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, object : Permissions.RunExpression {
                override fun expression() {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT)
                }
            }).permissionExecution()
```

2.

```kotlin
Permissions(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, object : Permissions.RunExpression {
                override fun expression() {
                    writeFileToLocation(file, locationPath)
                }
            }).permissionExecution()
```

Comment: You could have done the same with the signature you used in code posted with question. What is the difference?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu, the solution I provided above uses a class with single method interface to achieve that. But my enquiry is to know if there exist a way i could just use a function with method signature `permissionExecution(childFragment: Fragment, permission: String, expression: ????)` where `????` is the type that represents any arbitrary method.

Comment: You could have just put the same signature ??? as `() -> Unit` for the exact same results, call like `permissionExecution(childfragment, permission) { startActivityForResult(...) }`

Comment: calling it that way will only work for method with signature `method1()` and for method2 of form `method2(first, second)` will require another overload of signature `(firstType, secondType) -> Unit` and for all methods with different signature, I will need to write another overloads for them which is not what I want

Comment: Nope it doesnt, you are calling a lambda not the function there. As you are calling lambda with no parameter `runExpression()` you have to make signature `() -> Unit`, it is "exactly" same as interface.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I totally get it now. Guess I should have moved back a little and look at the solution provided by @Tenfour04

Answer (score 0):

a better way i find by adapting the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41649535/pass-interface-as-parameter-in-kotlin/41649585) is firstly, create an interface like this

```
interface RunExpression{
fun expression()}
```

then use the interface in the function signature

```
fun permissionExecution(childFragment: Fragment, permission : String, runExpression: RunExpression) {

Dexter.withActivity(childFragment.requireActivity())
    .withPermission(permission)
    .withListener(object : PermissionListener {
        override fun onPermissionGranted(response: PermissionGrantedResponse?) {
            runExpression.expression()
        }

        override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
            permission: PermissionRequest?,
            token: PermissionToken
        ) {
            token.continuePermissionRequest()
        }

        override fun onPermissionDenied(response: PermissionDeniedResponse) {
            if(response.isPermanentlyDenied) {
                openSettings(childFragment)
            }
        }

    }).check()}
```

then wherever I want to call the function, I save the anonymous object that implement the interface into a variable

```
val startMyActivity = object : RunExpression {
            override fun expression() {
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT)
            }
        }
```

then call the function with the variable

```
permissionExecution(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, startMyActivity)
```